# Brightcove Media API Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: brightcove

I'm attempting to call the Media API but am getting an Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

I tried appending '?jsoncallback=?' to my url (JSONP) and it now returns the JSON file but my browser is trying to interpret it as javascript and throwing an error.

```
(function() {
  var mediaAPI = "http://api.brightcove.com/services/library?jsoncallback=?";
  $.getJSON( mediaAPI, {
    command: "find_video_by_id",
    video_id: "2472866007001",
    video_fields: "videoStillURL,thumbnailURL",
    media_delivery: "http",
    token: "4kDMVfqenhDk_uU2MvV8fioVrHsHwiKWCLFuxZumIq7fSa3wyRkTNw..",
    format: "json"
  })
  .done(function( data ) {


    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    alert( obj.name === "videoStillURL" );

  });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `callback` instead of `jsoncallback` the Media API will return a JSONP response (JSON wrapped in a callback function)

You shouldn't use `jQuery.parseJSON()` with that type of response, `alert(obj.videoStillURL)` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Change `format: "json"` to `format: "jsonp"`... should fix it for you